# How can we trace history of transactions in smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

Once the contract is mined, i receive an address. Several transactions take place on that contract address, for which a unique transaction hash is generated for each transaction. These transactions change the state and force certain parameters to change.

Is there a way to trace those transactions/ state change using the contract address in smart contracts?

Answer (score 1):

We're trying to build a command line tool to download and present transactions at http://ethslurp.com. It's a work in progress, but it's open source, so it might shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://etherscan.io/ to trace the transaction history for an address.

Etherscan is an ethereum blockchain explorer. Search by the address and you'll get see transaction history for the address.